# How to deal with large amount of sentences with gensim word2vec?

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec

I have a very large amount of sentences, the problem is i cannot load them all at once in memory, specially when i tokenize the sentences and split them into list of words my RAM goes full really fast.

but i couldn't find any example of how can i train the gensim word2vec with batches, meaning in each epoch i guess i have to somehow load batches of data from disk, tokenize them and give it to the model then unload it and load the next batch.

how can i overcome this problem and train a word2vec model when i don't have enough ram to load all the sentences (not even 20% of them).

my sentences are basically in a text file, each line representing a sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own corpus as suggested in [docs](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_word2vec.html#training-your-own-model) and basically size of corpus doesn't matter in this case:

```
from gensim.test.utils import datapath
from gensim import utils

class MyCorpus(object):
    """An interator that yields sentences (lists of str)."""

    def __iter__(self):
        corpus_path = datapath('lee_background.cor')
        for line in open(corpus_path):
            # assume there's one document per line, tokens separated by whitespace
            yield utils.simple_preprocess(line)
```

Then train it as follow:

```
import gensim.models

sentences = MyCorpus()
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences=sentences)
```

Comment: Note that if the text is already broken into one-text-per-line, and already space-separated, you can reuse the `LineSentence` class (https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.LineSentence) to do the streaming from disk. (You don't need to write your own iterable corpus class, and if you may have already done better tokenization than `simple_preprocess()` can do.)

Comment: @gojomo it gives me error when i use build_vocab after the Word2Vec api call : runtimeError: cannot sort vocabulary after model weights already initialized. currently after building the Word2vec model,  i am using build_vocab(sentences) and then train(sentences , ...), how should i change this?

Comment: It sounds like you may have supplied a training corpus when you created the model. If you do that, it will have already done the `.build_vocab()` and `.train()` steps for you – so you'll get an error if you try it again.